# How to configure docker container volumes in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, mounted-volumes

I have several `volumes` defined in my `docker-compose.dev.yml` (from my source to docker container) .

```
  backend:
    build:
      context: ...
      args: ...
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

I want to deploy my container in AWS ECS (Amazon Elastic Container Service).

1. How can I map these volumes in AWS ECS ?
2. Why source volume only contains `none` ?

[image]